# MVC4 Pass @Html.DropDownList SelectedItem value to @Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select, html.actionlink

I have a DropDownList, and I want to pass the selected value into the ActionLink. How do I pull the selected value?

```
@Html.DropDownList( "DataCollectionsList", (SelectList)ViewBag.AvailableDataCollections, new { onChange = "runAlert();"} )
@Ajax.ActionLink( "test123", "AddDataCollection", new { reportId = Model.ReportId, dataCollectionId = **INSERT SELECTED DROPDOWN VALUE HERE** }, new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "test123" } )
```

Comment: I would go for a javascript/jquery thing to do this.

Comment: I was thinking that as well, but i figured there might be a helper method to pull values from a specified id

Comment: nope no such helper method. pull it out yourself.